# $X$ is a random variable with finite mean, prove that $E(\ln X) \leq \ln (EX)$. Also show that the inequality is strict unless $X$ is degenerate.

Tags: statistics

I used the fact that the function $x\mapsto\ln(x)$ is concave. Hence using Jensen's inequality i could get $E(\ln X) \leq \ln (EX)$. But, I need some hint regarding the rest.

Comment: Have you tried looking at how Jensen's inequality is proven, and see what you can do there using the fact that $\ln$ is *strictly* concave?

Comment: That, or search for the word "equality" in [the WP page on Jensen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Comment: @Did :  I don't think the Wikipedia page answers the question. [mod edited]

Comment: And yet it does.

Comment: @Did : In two places it asserts a sufficient condition. In one place it asserts a necessary condition, but only in a case involving a random variable with only finitely many values. And all three are just assertions.

Comment: IOW the WP page does provide the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\e}{\operatorname{E}}$If $X$ is not degenerate, and only if $X$ is not degenerate, there is some number $c$ for which $\Pr(X\ge c)>0$ and $\Pr(X<c)>0.$ Then one has
$$
\e(X) = \e(X\mid X<c)\Pr(X<c) + \e(X\mid X\ge c)\Pr(X\ge c).
$$
And then
\begin{align}
& \e(\ln X) = \e(\ln X\mid X<c)\Pr(X<c) + \e(\ln X\mid X\ge c)\Pr(X\ge c) \\[10pt]
\le {} & \ln\e(X\mid X<c)\Pr(X<c) + \ln\e(X\mid X\ge c) \Pr(X\ge c) \\
& \quad \text{by using Jensen's inequality twice.}
\end{align}
Then use strict convexity of the logarithm function.